# How to use values read from html for variables

Tags: python, html, jquery, ajax, mongodb

i'm trying to use mongodb and ajax. i want to load data from database which has the same name with radiobutton's value.
it kinda like this.

```
@app.route('/Dessert', methods=['POST'])
def read_dessert():
    selecteddb = request.form['dessert_give']

    data_list = list(ddb.selecteddb.find({},{'_id':False}))
    return jsonify({'result': selecteddb})
```

and ajax from index.html

```
   function send_dessert() {
        let dessert = $(":input:radio[name=type]:checked").val()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Dessert",
            data: {dessert_give: dessert},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                alert('dataload complete')

            }
        });
```

however, the result shows nothing, what should i do?
It was successful to load the database by directly declaring the values checked by radiobutton. However, I am doing this because I want to load different databases based on the values checked in radiobutton.

Comment: check if you're getting desired value for `dessert` variable under `send_dessert()`

Comment: i checked `dessert` with print it, it worked properly . It prints the values of the variables I want.. However, using the variable in the data_list causes problems.